# web-app_2_5.xsd showing errors when validating web.xml in Weblogic

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I have done a Dynamic Web project with Spring 3.0 using Tomcat Server & it works fine. When i deployed the same in Weblogic Server; it throws me an error:

```
VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '2.5' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee: at 
weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:245) at 
weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:231) at 
weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:155) at 
weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323) ---
weblogic.application.ModuleException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
```

Starting lines of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

But the same works in Tomcat.

Comment: Is there any differences between Tomcat deployment & Weblogic deployment, as i am very new top it. PLease let me the know the issue if anyone knos the solution.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: maybe your version of Weblogic is too old for Servlet 2.5 support. Which version are you using?

Comment: "version" attribute is not mandatory in web.xml, just remove it.

Comment: @skaffman is right - are you trying on weblogic 7 ?

Comment: Weblogic version is 9.2 but i don't think it is the problem or it can be..not sure...so what you people would suggest to use Weblogic which version for Servlet2.5 version?

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic 9.2, which you are apparently using, is a J2EE 1.4 appserver. Servlet 2.5 is a JavaEE 5 API, and is therefore not supported. Your server only goes as high as Servlet 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have display-name tag, in my case I had the tag display-name which was causing the grief, also I changed the namespace from _http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee to _http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

eg:

```
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLon="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
```